# What is the benefit of using :root CSS selector instead of html CSS selector?

Tags: css, css-selectors

In HTML documents the `:root` pseudo-class selector introduced in CSS3 is equal to `html` selector, with the only difference is that `:root` has a higher specificity.
If they are almost the same, then what are the practical benefits of using `:root`?

I have read that `:root` selector is useful for declaring a global CSS variable, i.e. a variable accessible in the whole HTML code. However I can set a variable using `html` selector, and it will be available in the whole HTML code as well. The only benefit I found on https://alligator.io/css/root-pseudo-class/ is that a CSS variable set in `:root` can also be used to style SVG graphics. Is it the only benefit?

Comment: Please, add some code snippet to make this question as a reference.

Comment: @SaidbakR, Unfortunately, I don't know SVG, so I cannot give any SVG example. I asked the question because I only wanted to know the differences between the `:root` and `html` selectors in pure HTML documents. The only difference in HTML is in specificity: `:root` has (0,1,0) specificity i.e. one pseudo-class, and `html` has (0,0,1) specificity i.e. one element.

Comment: @SaidbakR, I also don't know any situation where I would need a specificity greater than (0,0,1) for the `html` selector, because I use `html` selector rarely.

Answer (score 9):

You pretty-much answered your own question with the last bit about `:root` matching both `<html>` and `<svg>` - or any other root element in non-HTML documents.

Remember that CSS is also designed to be compatible with more than just HTML and SVG, it's also designed to be compatible with XML, and with XML the root element might share the same element-name as a child-element - so this is a way to work with those kinds of documents because CSS offers no other way of selecting *only the root* element for styling, so it's in the same family as `:first-child`, `:first-of-type`, `:last-of-type`, etc.

I'll add there's also the risk that a malformed HTML document *might* have an illegal `<html>` element located elsewhere in the DOM. If you use just `html` as a selector then those additional `<html>` elements will also be styled, which would break your site's layout if you have the commonplace `html { min-height: 100%; height: 100%; }` rule. Changing it to `html:root { ... }` fixes that.